# Is there an intent for Calendar reminder alarm?

Tags: android, calendar, android-intent

I would like to suggest a new layout for Calender Reminder.

Is there a way to be notifiyed when ever a Calender Reminder is on and alarming,
or I have creat and manage my own calendar and events to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to be notifiyed when ever a Calender Reminder is on and alarming, or I have creat and manage my own calendar and events to implement this?

You will have to "creat and manage [your] own calendar and events to implement this".